# Where are the Sonatype Nexus LDAP config files located?

Tags: ldap, nexus

We have an old Sonatype Nexus (version 2.11.2) running for some older applications. We had it set up for LDAP, but now I can no longer login with my ID. There are no error messages in the logs when I try to login.

All the documentation I see for setting up LDAP is for the UI. I did a recursive case-insensitive search for `ldap` in the Nexus install directory, as well as our LDAP server host name, but I'm not finding anything that ever remotely looks like LDAP configuration info.

Where is the LDAP configuration info stored for Nexus when you do it from the UI? And is there some way for me to turn on more verbose logging?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See here for information on how to reset the administration password on Nexus 2.x:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465508-How-can-I-reset-a-forgotten-admin-password-

Once you're in you can check your LDAP configuration.

Comment: This does not response the question ? Where are the Sonatype Nexus LDAP config files located?

Comment: It's in a database, there is no configuration file you can edit like t here was in 2.x.

Comment: @rseddon, the question specifically asks for 2.11.2.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP configuration is stored in **`${nexus-work}/conf/ldap.xml`**

From the [installation guide](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/installing-and-running/installing) about `nexus-work`:

> By default, this directory is always a sibling to the installation directory. If you installed the repository manager in the `/usr/local` directory, it would also contain a `sonatype-work` subdirectory with a nested `nexus` directory containing all of the content and configuration. The location of the sonatype-work directory can be customized by altering the **`nexus-work`** property in `$NEXUS_HOME/conf/nexus.properties`.

`$NEXUS_HOME`is the installation directory.

Comment: this .xml file isn't there in my directory. I have installed nexus 3.65 PRO

Comment: @DarshanaPatel The questions and its answer are about version 2. According to rseddon's comment to the other answer, in version 3 it's in the database, there is no configuration file any more.